# How to control a laptop CPU fan?

Tags: fan, laptop

I have a spare laptop fan but I have no idea how to control (or even power) it. It has Red, Yellow, Blue and Black wires. I assumed red is +5V and black is your normal ground, but after applying 5v it doesn't move. Does it need any control signal, clock? I don't think it's that much sophisticated. I'd like to have it on all the time, how can I do it?

[image: laptop fan]

Comment: The yellow and blue wires are for PWM control and either a tachometer or locked rotor signal.  You'll have to check the datasheet for the fan to see which is which; I've seen it both ways.  However, the fan should run at 100% if the PWM wire is open-circuited.  Do you have reason to believe that the fan is broken?

Comment: Note that it is marked (right on the fan body) that it is a 5V fan, not a 12V one.  Connecting red to +5V and black to 0V (with yellow and blue unconnected to anything) should spin it.  If not, it's faulty.